# Increment a value with PHP ternary operator

Tags: php

How can I increment `$x` using the ternary operator?

I've tried `$x = $x==2 ? 0 : ++;` but obviously it didn't work.

```
if($x == 2 ){ 
    $x=0; 
}else{ 
    $x++; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use pre-increment here.

```
$x = ($x==2) ? 0 : ++$x;
```

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/gZwLCbMG)**

Comment: Why $x++ doesn't work? I can't find an explanation... How can it be that a pre increment does work and a post increment doesn't?

Comment: @greg: `++$x` increments the value and then assigns it to `$x`, `$x++` assigns `$x` first and *then* increments the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't get it... in both cases it executes two operations. So lets put the case that $x = 1. It founds that  $x==2 is false therefore: 
executing $x++ will assign $x = 1 and then increments the value, so $x = 2... at the end I should still have $x = 2.
executing ++$x will increment the value to 2 and then assign it to $x. So again, $x = 2.
In the following case I would understand the difference between ++$y and $y++:
$x = ($x==2) ? 0 : $y++   => $x = 1 and $y = 2
$x = ($x==2) ? 0 : ++$y   => $x = 2 and $y = 2

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this would be:

```
$x = $x === 2 ? 0 : $x+1;
```

If you insist on using a ternary just to increment the var:

```
$x += $x === 2 ? $x*(-1) : 1;//or hard-code -2 instead of $x*(-1)
```

This either adds 1 to `$x` or adds `$x*-1` to $x (`$x + (-$x)` is 0). On the whole, though, I'd like to add that ternary (especially in PHP) should be avoided as much as possible. In this case, writing:

```
if (++$x === 3)
{
    $x = 0;
}
```

Does exactly the same thing, and isn't *that* much more code, though it does look a lot nicer. Even so, the increment in an if statement is still messy, best increment beforehand, or:

```
$x = $x === 2 ? -1 : $x;
$x++;
```

If you've got a strange preference for ternaries... and if it *has* to be a one-liner:

```
$x = ($x ===2 ? -1 : $x) +1;
```

works, too... but there's a [code-golfing site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for these kind of things...

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for letting me know about the code-golfing site!

Answer (score -2):

Why don't use module operator for that ?

```
$x = ++$x % 2;
```

Comment: Actually if `x` manages to get set to 3 somewhere else then this modulus operator would give a different result. But that's down to what the OP actually wants (could be a bug in the logic!)